# Compute variance of a triangle distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

How to compute the variance for the random variable Y that has the triangle distribution:

$$f_Y(x) = \begin{cases}
             4x,\;0\leq x\ \leq \frac12 \\
             2-4x, \; \frac12 \leq x \leq 1 
       \end{cases} \quad$$
The answer should be $\frac{1}{24}$ but I don't know how to get this. This is what I have done:
$$\mu_Y = \int_{\frac12}^{0} 4x\cdot x \,dx +\int_{1}^{\frac12} (2-4x)\cdot x \,dx = -0.25$$
$$\text{Var}(Y) = E(Y^2) - \mu_Y^2 = \int_{\frac12}^{0} 4x\cdot (x+0.25)^2 \,dx +\int_{1}^{\frac12} (2-4x)\cdot (x+0.25)^2 \,dx$$
I could not get the correct answer and did not have a clear idea what I've done incorrectly. Any help will be appraciated.

Comment: You are using a non-standard order of integration borders (higher number should stand high), therefore, while exchanging the integral with the antiderivative values, you may have gotten false signs.

Comment: And how did you came up with $(x + 0,25)^2$? Why not only $x^2$ (law of unconscious statistician)?

Comment: Definition of $f_Y(x)$ is bad.   $2-4x \le 0$ for upper half.